# Play video in app instead of default player

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie, video-player

I use the following code to play videos:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie=
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
    theMovie.moviePlayer.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
```

This causes a the default movie player to cover the app. Instead I want the video to play inside the app itself as follows:

[image]

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set its frame like this:

```
theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);
```

Then without presenting it add it as subview:

```
[self.view addSubview: theMovie.view];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: It seems author of the question doesn't want to play video assets in a separate view controller but wants to play them in a child view of his/her own view controller.

Comment: @NikolayMamaev > Did you see the screenshot he attached? My solution will allow him to play video in the same view controller.

Comment: sorry, IMHO your solution is totally incorrect. If you use the same variables as in the original question then `theMovie` is of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` type. So the following line from your answer won't work: `[self.view addSubview: theMovie];`, because the `addSubview:` method expects argument of the `UIView` type, not `UIViewController`

Comment: I don't know, I have never tried this approach. Adding a view managed by one view controller to another view controller is not the best idea.

Comment: I've tried this method. It works but if I show an action sheet it crashes. I find that I need to stop the movie ` [theMovie.moviePlayer stop];` then I'm able to show the action sheet.

Comment: @Ketan > I don't know why people downvoted this? btw you are welcome.

Comment: @Rashad i think they misunderstood. Unfortunately, i can't upvote, i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I also find that this solution hides the status bar. To fix it, I use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=NO;` after adding to the subview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be achieved by using the AVPlayerLayer. Please see examples here:

- ["AV Foundation Programming Guide", "Putting It All Together: Playing a Video File Using AVPlayerLayer" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW2)
- [A tutorial from the iosguy.com](http://iosguy.com/tag/avplayerlayer/)
- [Appuccino's "Playing Movies With AVPlayerLayer In iOS 6" video tutporial](http://youtu.be/cT9vPwOcmng)